# Unable to ssh tunnel while connected to VPN

Tags: ssh, networking, vpn, vmware, ssh-tunneling

I am trying to SSH tunnel in a guest VM that will connect to a VPN and give access to the host to otherwise blocked urls. All access is correct regarding keys.

- Host = Connecting via the ssh tunnel (Linux)
- Guest = Connects to VPN and is being tunneled to. (OSx 10.13)

Guest has 2 network cards.

1. **VPN network**

   1. IP: 192.168.238.130
   2. Router: 192.168.238.130
   3. DNS Server: 192.168.238.2
2. **Host Only network for the tunnel**

   1. IP: 192.168.138.130
   2. Router: Empty
   3. DNS Server: 192.168.138.1

## No connection to VPN

When I am not connected to the VPN I can connect to the guest very easily:

```
hutber@hutber ~ $ ssh -L 3333:github.someprivateurl.net:22 hutber@192.168.138.130
Password:
hutber@Jamies-Mac ~ $ //ssh access to guest
```

## When connected to VPN

```
hutber@hutber ~ $ ssh -L 3333:github.someprivateurl.net:22 hutber@192.168.138.130
.... (hangs)
```

Answer (score 1):

add the `-v` option to the ssh command to get a verbose output of what is happening and provide that back to be able to better see what the issue is.

Since i got Jeff a little upset,
It may be related to MTU - check this link out and see if you expiernce the same issue.

http://fred-web.blogspot.com/2012/10/ssh-hang-on-expecting.html

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/249764)

Comment: Yes i know i was going to Edit my response once he provided the information.

Comment: A comment is the appropriate venue for this, until there’s an Answer.